# ehtereum smart contract approve spender from another contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain

I have a erc20 token and in another contract I want to create a token swap function.
So very easily, one send a usdc token and swap my erc20 token in 1:1 ratio.
Problem is how to approve to spend my erc20 token. I tried several times but can't find a way.

```
interface IERC20 {...} 

contract AnotherContract {

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _amount) public returns(bool) {
    return IERC20(MyToken).approve(_spender, _amount);
}
```

I deployed this another contract and when I call approve function from it. So When I set '_spender' to this contract address. The result is weird. So this contract is owner and spender both.. As I think a user should be as a owner and this contract should be a spender. But function calling from onchain. the msg.sender is going to be this contract address self.

I don't understand and am confusing. anybody knows or have some rescoures? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your `AnotherContract` executes the `approve()` function in `MyToken`, the `msg.sender` in `MyToken` is `AnotherContract` - not the original transaction sender.

Which effectively approves `AnotherContract`'s tokens to be spent by `_spender`.

---

Unless the `MyToken` has a way to delegate the approval (e.g. by using a deprecated `tx.origin` instead of `msg.sender`, which introdues a security flaw), the user will have to **execute the approval manually**, and not through your external contract.

Many ERC-20 implementations use this approach for security purposes. For example to prevent a situation, where a scammer would persuade a user to execute their malicious function, because the user would think they are getting an airdrop.

```
// function name suggests that the caller is going to receive an airdrop
function claimAirdrop() external {
     /*
      * fortunately, this won't work
      * and the tx sender can't approve the scammer to spend their tokens this way
      */
    USDTcontract.approve(scammer, 1000000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you~. To be honest I don't understand the smart contract logics well now. I solved my problem like one time request an approve outside of the contract and request a transaction to spend user token (in allowances).

Comment: @Seong how did you do it? Can you a example code?

Comment: @seongcheolryu  how did you do it? Can you a example code?