# How can i get my token funded with LINK from user through solidity?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

My contract needs LINK token in order to function.

I want to let users fund LINK tokens to the contract via a function on the contract, and then do some logic for the user based on their funding.

How can i make this possible within the contract?
I've tried to do calls like this.

LINK.balanceOf(walletaddress) does work, (It gets the link amount that's in the wallet).
However, this function below does not work for some reason.
It goes through and all, but with like empty data.

Metamask shows differently when i do the same call from their front-end button. (I assume it does the same as remix does)

https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0x84b9B910527Ad5C03A9Ca831909E21e236EA7b06#readContract

Here is how i try to get my contracts approval.

```
function approveTransfer(uint256 amount) public returns(string memory) {
        uint256 approveAmt = amount * 10**18;
        LINK.approve(_msgSender(),approveAmt);
        approvedAmount = approveAmt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible from within your contract, unless the external contract explicitly allows it or contains a security flaw using deprecated `tx.origin` instead of `msg.sender`.

See the last paragraph and code snippet in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67385126/1693192) to see how it could be misused if it were possible.

---

When `your contract` executes LINK's function, `msg.sender` in the `LINK contract` is now `your contract` - not the user.

Both `transfer()` and `approve()` (in order to call `transferFrom()` later) functions rely on `msg.sender`, which you need to be the user. But it's not - it's your contract.

---

When `your contract` delegates a call to LINK's function, the state changes are stored in `your contract` - not in the LINK.

But you'd need to store the state changes in the LINK contract, so this is not an option either.

Comment: If i do it this way though, how can the contract know when someone deposits LINK tokens to it?

Comment: @DanielM Your contract can call LINK's contract function `balanceOf()` with the argument of your contract. Which will return the LINK balance of your contract... Example: Your contract is `0x123`, LINK contract is `0x456`. `0x123` calls `0x456` function `balanceOf(0x123)`.

Comment: But the contract wouldn't know who funded the tokens this way(What addres they came from in the contract itself)?

Comment: is there any way to do it so that the contract knows which address deposited ?

Comment: A contract directly - no. But you can have an offchain app that subscribes to event logs produced by transactions to LINK contract. And when any of the transactions produces a `Transfer()` event where the second argument (`address to`) is your contract - the offchain app can send a transaction to your contract, notifying it about new LINK transfer.

Comment: Welp, there goes the dream of making my DAPP fully decentralized :/
Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so i kept searching and searching and searching....

Until i found something amazing on their discord channel. (It's most likely written somewhere else too).

**Harry | Chainlink**

> The LINK token is an ERC677 with transferAndCall functionality. So
> depending on how your smart contract function call that generates the
> random number is made, you can change it to be a 'transferAndCall'
> function instead of one that just does the VRF request, with the idea
> being that it will transfer enough LINK to fulfill the VRF request.
> Then in your consuming contract that does the VRF request, you
> implement the 'onTokenTransfer' function which simply calls your other
> function that does the VRF request. The end result of this is that
> when the user transfers LINK to the contract, it automatically does a
> VRF request all in the 1 single transaction.
>
> So instead of the user pressing a button which calls the function in
> your consuming contract to do the VRF request, they press a button
> which does a 'transferAndCall' function from the LINK token contract,
> which in turn transfer LINK to your consuming contract and calls the
> 'onTokenTransfer' function in your consuming contract, which then
> calls your function to do the VRF request, which will be successfully
> fulfilled because it just received LINK for the request
> See an implementation of this in my previous hackathon entry "Link Gas Station"

> https://github.com/pappas999/Link-Gas-Station/blob/master/contracts/WeatherCheck.sol
> https://github.com/pappas999/Link-Gas-Station/blob/master/src/relayer/relayer.js

So in short, this is possible because my contract have the

```
function onTokenTransfer(address from, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)  public {
        receivedTokenTransfer = true;
        lastDepositer = from;
        lastDepositerAmountInLink = amount / 10**18;
    }
```

I can therefor instead of sending LINK to my own contract, i can send LINK to LINK's contract address, with the data payload transferAndCall , MycontractAddress, and the amount of LINK my contract should receive.

Upon this payment is sent, chainlink will send my contract the payment and call the function called `onTokenTransfer` (On my contract). :)))

Ho0pe this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Yes, `transferAndCall()` is a way that I forgot to focus on in my answer (only mentioned by "unless the external contract explicitly allows it" - which this is the case). It has a drawback - that the transfer will have to be done using this `transferAndCall()`. If anyone sends you tokens using the regular `transfer()` function, your contract (as the receiver) won't get notified... But if you have control over the transfer and can "force" your users to only use the `transferAndCall()` function, this is a way to go.

Comment: Awesome find !!