# How to interact with the deployed ERC20 token with another smart-contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I have created a basic ERC20 token by implementing OpenZeppelin as follow in ERC20.sol file:

```py
pragma solidity ^0.6.4;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol)
        public
        ERC20(_name, _symbol)
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000000000000000000000000000);
    }
}
```

Then implement another contract Contract.sol as follow:

```py
import "./ERC20.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.6.4;

contract SimpleBank{
    Token tokenContract;

    constructor(Token _tokenContract) public {
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
    }
    
    function deposit(uint amt) public returns (bool)  {
        require(amt != 0 , "deposit amount cannot be zero");
        tokenContract.transfer(address(this),amt);
        return true;
    }
}
```

As, I have deployed both contract from the address **0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2** so, it holds 10000000000000000000000000000 tokens.

But when I call `deposit` function from same address I got the following error:

> transact to SimpleBank.deposit errored: VM error: revert. revert The
> transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Reason provided by
> the contract: "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance". Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

So, what is the proper way to interact with the deployed ERC20 token so that the `deploy` function works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ehtereum smart contract approve spender from another contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67384106/ehtereum-smart-contract-approve-spender-from-another-contract)

Comment: The answer in the provided link isn't clear to me. Does it mean that another account can't interact with ERC20.sol  for security reasons? Can you help me with that @PetrHejda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The user address `0xAb8483...` sends a transaction executing `SimpleBank`'s function `deposit()`, which makes `0xAb8483...` the value of `msg.sender` in `SimpleBank`.
2. But then `SimpleBank` sends an internal transaction executing `Token`'s function `transfer()`. Which makes **`SimpleBank` address (not the `0xAb8483...`)** the value of `msg.sender` in `Token`.

   So the snippet `tokenContract.transfer(address(this),amt);` within SimpleBank is trying to send `SimpleBank`'s tokens. Not the user's (`0xAb8483...`) tokens.

This transfer of tokens (from point 2) reverts, because SimpleBank doesn't own any tokens. Which makes the top-level transaction (from point 1) revert as well.

---

If you want `SimpleBank` to be able to transfer `0xAb8483...`'s tokens, `0xAb8483...` needs to `approve()` the tokens first to be spent by `SimpleBank`. Directly from their address, so that they are `msg.sender` in the `Token` contract.

Only then `SimpleBank` can execute `transferFrom(0xAb8483..., address(this), amt)` (from, to, amount).

---

TLDR: Your contract can't spend tokens that it doesn't own, unless the owner has manually approved your contract to spend them.

If it could spend someone else's tokens without approval, it would be very easy to steal from people who can't/don't verify your source code (by spending their USDT, WETH and other widely-used tokens).

Comment: I tried the same, it failed for me though @Petr

Comment: @RohitMittal Please post a separate question with steps to reproduce your issue (e.g. how exactly you invoke the approval, on which network, ...).