# A Lottery Solidity Smart Contract Accept token as payment instead of ether

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Lottery {
  address public manager;
  address[] public players;

  constructor() public {
    manager = msg.sender;
  }

  function enter() public payable {
    require(msg.value > .01 ether);

    players.push(msg.sender);
  }

  function random() private view returns (uint) {
    return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
  }

  function pickWinner() public restricted {
    uint index = random() % players.length;

    players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);

    players = new address[](0);
  }

  function getPlayers() public view returns (address[]) {
    return players;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    _;
  }
}
```

I want o change the function

```
function enter() public payable {
    require(msg.value > .01 ether);

    players.push(msg.sender);
}
```

Instead of ether, user use our token/erc20 to enter the lottery

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface (in your contract) of the token contract. Since you're only going to be using the `transferFrom()` function, this is the only function that you need to define in the interface (no matter that the token contract contains other functions as well).

```
interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
}
```

The you can execute the `transferFrom()` function of the token, passing it arguments:

- from: the user executing your `enter()` function
- to: your contract
- amount: Assuming the token has 18 decimals (most tokens do), you can use the [ether](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units) helper unit, because it effectively calculates "0.01 * 10^18 (or 10^16, or 10000000000000000) of the token smallest units", which is 0.01 of the token. Otherwise, you'll need to recalculate this number based on the token decimals.

```
function enter() public payable {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(address(0x123)); // Insert the token contract address instead of `0x123`
    require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), .01 ether));

    players.push(msg.sender);
}
```

**Important**: Mind that the user needs to `approve()` your contract to spend their tokens beforehand (from their address), otherwise the token transfer would fail. There's a security reason for that, read more about it in the bottom part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642090/1693192).

Comment: Thank you for this, Can you give me an example to invoke user to approve token contract to use as their payment?

Comment: The user needs to execute the `approve()` function of the token contract (e.g. USDT), with arguments 1) your contract as the spender, 2) max amount of tokens that you're allowed to spend. Example: `approve(0x123, 1000)` - this will allow address `0x123` to spend `1000` token units (mind the decimals - if a token uses 18 decimals, this value would need to be 1000 * 10^18)... They can execute the function using their wallet software (only some have this feature) or some third party app. Or a webpage can prepare transaction executing the function and then just open a MetaMask window to confirm.

Comment: Sir one last question, can I change sa placeholder text of "payableAmount (BNB)" to payableAmount (TokenName)?

Comment: Where is the placeholder text? I can't see it in your question, nor the answer.