# Solidity - transfer amount exceeds spender allowance

Tags: transactions, ethereum, solidity, metamask

The code looking correct,approving token before transfering, but failing with error: "transfer amount exceeds spender allowance"
Sender account is having more than required token balance.

Any ideas?
Contract: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x2a855c479b14443489963eef90ad449ecdf40cf5#writeContract

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;  


interface IERC20 {
   function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
   function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool); 
   function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
} 
 
contract FundTokenContract { 
    address public owner;   
     
    constructor(){ 
        owner = msg.sender;
    }   
    
    modifier OnlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function.");
        _;
    } 
    
     function fundToken(address tokenAddress, uint amount ) external {  
        require(amount > 0);  
        IERC20(tokenAddress).approve(address(this), amount); 
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender ,address(this), amount);  
    }  
      
      
    function withdrawToken(address _tokenAddress, address  _recipient, uint _amount) public  OnlyOwner returns (bool){  
        IERC20(_tokenAddress).transfer(_recipient, _amount);
        return true;
    }  
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and share the `tokenIn` functions `approve()` and `transferFrom()` and their dependencies. Using the current code from your question, it's not possible to reproduce (and troubleshoot) your issue.

Comment: Hi, it's updated, please check on rinkeby address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your contract executes the `tokenAddress` function `approve()`, the `msg.sender` within the `approve()` function is **your contract** (not the user initiating the transaction).

Which effectively approves "your contract" (first argument `address(this)`) to spend "your contract"s (`msg.sender`) funds.

Then it's trying to `transferFrom()` the user address, but it doesn't have the approval.

---

If you want your contract to spend tokens that belong to another user, they need to execute the `approve(<yourContract>, <amount>)` from their address **directly** (not through a contract).

*Note: See the TLDR in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642090/1693192), it shows how this requirement is useful.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there any way to approve from contract in the same transaction?

Comment: @Giorgiu There's no way to do that, because of the security reasons explained in the linked answer.